# How do I generate a heatmap from .geojson file?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, heatmap

Hi I want to generate a heatmap from a .geojson file with [this](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.heat) plugin

How can I manage that? I'm very new to json, leaflet and web development.

The geoJSON file I have looks something like this (with more points ofc):

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "testmarker",
        "description": "This is a test description"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -33.134766,
          -60.326948
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "testmarker2"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -41.220703,
          -62.552857
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is what my index.html looks like right now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html = style="height: 100%;">
  <head>
    <title>Test Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/leaflet.css">
    <script src="scripts/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/leaflet.ajax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/leaflet-heat.js"></script>
  </head>
  
  <body style="height: 100%;margin: 0;">
    <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #000000;"></div>
    
    <!-- Workaround for 1px lines appearing in some browsers due to fractional transforms
    and resulting anti-aliasing.-->
    <style>
    .leaflet-tile-container img {
    width: 256.5px !important;
    height: 256.5px !important;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Creating the Map
        var map = L.map('map').setView([58.602611, 50.350342], 4);

        L.tileLayer('maps/mymap/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        continuousWorld: false,
        noWrap: true,
        minZoom: 2,
        maxZoom: 6,
        zoomControl: false,
        minNativeZoom: 2,
        maxNativeZoom: 6,
        updateInterval: 200,
        }).addTo(map);

        // Remove old zoomControl and add new one in order to move it to bottomright
        map.zoomControl.remove();
        L.control.zoom({
        position: 'bottomright'
        }).addTo(map);

        // Binds tooltip on all markers and also a popup on click if the markers has a description
        function oef(feature, layer) {
            if (feature.properties && feature.properties.name) {
                layer.bindTooltip(feature.properties.name);
            }
            if (feature.properties && feature.properties.name && feature.properties.description) {
            layer.bindPopup("<center><b> " + feature.properties.name + "</center></b><br>" + feature.properties.description);
            }
        }

        var geojsonMarkers = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX(["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/***/test.geojson"],{onEachFeature:oef});

        var mapOverlays={
        "Test"                      : geojsonMarkers,
        //"Test - Heat Map"         : geojsonMarkersHeat,
        }

        var layerControl = L.control.layers(null, mapOverlays, {position:'topleft'}).addTo(map);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see from above I want the heatmap to be toggleable via the mapOverlays but I don't really know how to proceed.

Comment: Try this out [Heatmap with GeoJSON, Leaflet and Leaflet.heat plugin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/337294/heatmap-with-geojson-leaflet-and-leaflet-heat-plugin) .

Comment: I tried that now but i get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'features' of undefined"

Comment: Managed to get it working now! took some help fromt his post too https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101935/how-to-get-latlng-array-from-geojson-layer-in-leaflet